# SQL Server : how to get NEXTVAL of sequence from VIEW?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, view, sequence

I faced a problem in SQL Server with getting a nextval of a sequence from a view.
I know the solution for this case for Oracle and PostgreSQL:

- create sequence;
- create function/procedure, which call the sequence;
- create view, which call the function/procedure;

But in SQL Server, this approach doesn't work due to system restrictions.

Comment: There is a SEQUENCE solution to get next Int/bigint value(With SQL Server 2012). But I didn't understand why you want to use next value with view. Each execute you will see difference number. maybe you mean row_number()

Comment: Why would a view increment a sequence? That makes no sense at all. What possible real world situation could this be trying to solve?

Comment: @SeanLange . . . It would be a way to count the number of times that rows in the view have been accessed.

Comment: I have an application which should get an incremented value. But this app works only with views.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, that's a sneaky little trick that I kind of like. I'll keep that in my back pocket. Thanks!

Comment: @Jdzel if that so, you can use ROW_NUMBER() .

Comment: @GordonLinoff could you describe this approach?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I guess that would work. I have never needed to know how many times a row of data was viewed but theoretically can understand that might be needed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you show how that works? I have never seen it and I'm definately interested.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
--DROP TABLE TestTable
--GO
CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
    id  INT identity(1,1)
    ,[Name] VARCHAR(100)
)
GO
INSERT INTO TestTable
VALUES
('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F')
GO

--DROP VIEW TestView
--GO
CREATE  VIEW TestView
AS
SELECT   Id
        ,[Name]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) A
FROM TestTable
GO

SELECT * FROM TestView
```

Comment: This is not going to do what the OP wants. They want a persistent value, this does not do that. Or reading the comments maybe they don't in which case this is exactly what they need.